# How can i get rid of the message "Duplicate sources.list entry

Tags: software-sources

```
Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/restricted amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy_restricted_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_saucy_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build a default file following the procedure:

1. Move older file

   `sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak`
2. Then open `software-properties-gtk` to build a new one. Type the below command in a terminal

   `software-properties-gtk`

In the window

Select all four catagory in **Ubuntu Software** tab

Select *precise-security, precise-updates and precise-backports* catagory in **Updates** tab.

Select *Canonical partner* and *Intependent catagory* from **Other software** tab.

That's it. Now you will have a new deafault error free sources.list file.