# Flash player sometimes works, but sometimes doesn't

Tags: flash

I am on Ubuntu 12.04. I've been using Firefox and when I opened for example a Youtube link, the screen where the video is supposed to be is black and it displays an error. When I click on some recommended link for that video, and return back to the video with the error it starts playing normally.

I thought it is some problem with flash, so I installed Chromium (I found out it provides Flash), but there is the same problem again.  I have the Flash player plugin installed, also tried restricted extras, and HTML5 is enabled in Youtube...

Comment: No, Chromium does not include Flash. You should install [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/) which does provide Flash.

Comment: For me Chromium includes Flash in Ubuntu 12.04 and plays videos nicely. Can you edit the question and add the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa in my free translation, it says video isn't avaliable

Comment: "Video isn't available" is an error message you can get at certain websites due to poor internet connection. It is not related to the Flash plug-in per se. I would strongly advise you against using Chrome, especially since you already have Chromium installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to make flash-player work in Ubuntu 12.04 is not present in the official repositories. You need first to open Synaptic Package manager, go to Synaptic - Settings - Repositories - Other Software, and once you're there you should check 'Canonical Partners' entry and 'Independent' entry. There is no need to also check the Source Code packages for the same sources.

Close Software Sources window, and reload Synaptic repositories with the Reload button. Next look for and install adobe-flashplugin and adobe-flash-properties-gtk. Or you can close Synaptic and run this code in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin adobe-flash-properties-gtk
```

Remove first the other flash player related packages like flashplugin-installer or similar.

If you don't really want to use flash-player you can use Mozilla Firefox which has 2 nice addons to play video without flash. One is 'VideoWithoutFLash' addon, and the other one is 'Open With' addon. You need to configure these addons after restarting Firefox otherwise they won't work as expected. 'Open With' addon, for instance, has a list of default applications which it uses when streaming video is to be played. I for one use VLC, and you can add VLC player or other player (mplayer2, xine) in the list, delete all other entries, and this way you'll be able to watch videos with vlc as an embedded player.

Comment: tried synaptic, i've got this message:



W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise/partner amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages)

Comment: Try this workaround, maybe you'll get rid of those error messages: http://askubuntu.com/questions/384157/how-can-i-get-rid-of-the-message-duplicate-sources-list-entry

Comment: Do you use Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit? I never tested Ubuntu 64 bit, and I am not sure about the  sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin adobe-flash-properties-gtk  code for Ubuntu 64 bit. Anyway, if you do use Ubuntu 64 bit, you should look for **adobe-flashplugin** for 64 bit and also for the appropriate **adobe-flash-properties** package.

Comment: 64 bit, tried all that. thank you, anyway

Comment: I am sorry nothing works for you. Still, they have clear instructions for you problem in here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AMD64/FirefoxAndPlugins

Comment: thanks also for the link, it's very helpfull for me. solved by installing chrome, instead of chromium

Comment: Great! Now all you have to do is to wait until April 17th when they release Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as a stable distro. I heard it is better than Ubuntu 12.04 and definitely better than Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird possibility but is your flash grabbing a sound card? Flash will show some things normally but will stop working if it cannot find what sound card you are using. If your `aplay -l` output from terminal is not listing anything, then there is no soundcard to grab. If your `sudo aplay -l` gives you an output, then you have user/group permissions to configure. Hope this helps.

Comment: **** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0